# Error in PROLOG program

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

In the code below, i'm getting error in **sister** function that *"Illegal character"* in **

> Blockquote

Person \= P1** (\= is for not equal to)

> Blockquote

DOMAINS
    Person = SYMBOL

PREDICATES
    parent(Person,Person)
    female(Person)
    male(Person)
    mother(Person,Person)
    father(Person,Person)
    grandfather(Person,Person)
    grandmother(Person,Person)
    sister(Person,Person)

CLAUSES
    female(merry).
    female(syndra).
    female(juliet).
    female(lisa).

```
male(parker).
male(peter).
male(herry).
male(bob).
male(paul).

parent(juliet,lisa).
parent(bob,lisa).
parent(bob,paul).
parent(bob,merry).

parent(juliet,paul).
parent(juliet,merry).
parent(peter,herry).
parent(lisa,herry).
parent(merry,parker).
parent(merry,syndra).

father(X,Person):-parent(X,Person) , male(X).
mother(X,Person):-parent(X,Person) , female(X).

grandfather(X,Person):-parent(Y,Person),father(X,Y).
grandmother(X,Person):-parent(Y,Person),mother(X,Y).

sister(X,Person):-parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Person),Person \= P1,female(Person).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about, and I can't try because I don't have Turbo Prolog right now, but I vaguely remember that *Variables* doesn't need to be declared.

And I suspect that Child should be Person instead (after all, a Child *is* a Person). Try to simplify in this way

```
DOMAINS

Person = SYMBOL

PREDICATES

parent(Person,Person)
female(Person)
male(Person)
mother(Person,Person)
...
```